# Как фильтровать более чем одно расширение?

Tags: c#

Как добавить несколько расширений: `var set = new HashSet<string> { "*.exe", "*.bat", "*.reg" };` в `GetFiles()` ?

```
foreach (var Search in new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\Loader\").GetFiles("*.exe"))// <- Сюда
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через Linq

```
string[] extensions = new string[] {".gif",".jpg"};
dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension))
```

Comment: inline  не сработал. А в низу было ещё решение, вот оно сработало, почему его удалили? ))

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин э-э-э, а почему вы считаете что GetFiles() работает лучше чем EnumerateFiles()?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, согласно документации, и то и другое работает.

Comment: @GooliveR а что именно не работает?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин согласно документации, рекомендуется использовать второй метод на больших директориях. То есть первый метод ограничен в применении, в то время как второй - нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] extensions = new string[] { ".txt", ".sql" }; 
var array_files_all = Directory.GetFiles(@"sql\", "*").Where(f => extensions.Any(w => f.Contains(w))).Select(a => a.ToString());
string[] array_files = new string[array_files_all.Count()];//выбор всех файлов нужной кодировки
int n = 0;
foreach (var file in array_files_all)
{
    array_files[n] = file;
    n++;
}
```